# Counting Involving Two Different Sets

Tags: combinatorics

So I have two sets: `C` (the set of all capital letters) and `D` (the set of all single digits). Let's say `c ∈ C` and `d ∈ D` are arbitrary elements in those sets.

I have two counting problems that I can't seem to wrap my head around:

(1) A username must consist of 3 capital letters and 1 digit. How many possible user names?

I'm thinking of this as an extension of Cartesian Products, so I'd have something that would result in `(c, c, c, d) ∈ (C x C x C x D)`. But I need every possible ordering of this product so that would mean `|(C x C x C x D)|` multiplied by `4!`, since there are 4 spaces. Is this reasoning correct?

(2) How many possible usernames if a username must consist of `exactly` five capital letters and `exactly` four digits?

This seems very similar to (1), but I am not sure if the word "exactly" changes anything. Here is my solution, with similar reasoning as with (1): `|(C x C x C x C x C x D x D x D x D)|*9!`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solve the second problem. The first is the same, except simpler. We assume that the letters and/or digits can be in any order. We also assume that digits, caps can repeat.

**Where** shall the digits go? There are $9$ slots, and we must choose $4$ of them. This can be done in $\binom{9}{4}$ ways.

For **each** such choice, the digit slots can be filled in $10^4$ ways, and for each such filling, the remaining slots can be filled with caps in $26^5$ ways,

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I am understanding this correctly, would we have C(9, 4)*(10^4)*C(9, 5)*(26^5) ways of doing this (by the product rule)?

Comment: Not quite. Once we have decided on the slots for the digits, there is only one place for the caps to go, so it should be $\binom{5}{5}$ or leave it out. The answer is $\binom{9}{4}10^4 26^5$.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. But What is your reasoning behind using C(9, 4) instead of P(9, 4)?

Comment: I am choosing $4$ locations. The order in which I choose them is not relevant. As a side comment, students would be better off if the notation $P(n,k)$ was never introduced.

Comment: Okay, I see now. I get a little mixed up when order does or does not matter. 

I am curious, why do you say P(n, k) is bad notation?

Comment: It is not particularly bad as a string of symbols, but forever it gives rise to the student question do I use $C(n,k)$ or $P(n,k)$. That question tends to short-circuit analysis of the problem.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. One of the things that gets in the way of learning mathematics is the belief that one formula is always the key to solving a problem. That is good strategy in most high school courses, and, sadly, even in some university courses, but it produces bad long term results.

Comment: I agree, Mathematics is more than just plugging in numbers to formulas and number crunching. There's a bit of cleverness and ingenuity involved. I'll keep this in mind as I move forward in my undergraduate mathematics courses.